# What do you call this keyboard spinner(?) and how do I replace it with Spinner?

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uKuuS.jpg Keyboard Spinner(?)

I've been using a Spinner in my application and the number of items that should be in the Spinner is a lot more than i thought and the spinner scroll bar is quite small already due to the number of items. I thought it'd look cleaner if I used this Keyboard Spinner just like the one in the image that I linked above where the keyboard turns into like a selection. But I don't know what it's called and how to replace the Spinner im using with it.

Sorry for bad english. I'm new to stackoverflow hope someone could help :)

Comment: that's native to iOS, what you have shown in the picture.

Answer (score 1):

What you posted is indeed native to iOS, this is a very bad choice design wise.

I would highly recommend to use **Exposed Dropdown Menus** from the new material components lib https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/

This introduces a way to implement a "spinner" using a `AutoCompleteTextView` so users can type part of the input before selecting the item.

Here is an example of how that would look like:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox.ExposedDropdownMenu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="@string/hint_text">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/filled_exposed_dropdown"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

More information can be found here:

https://material.io/develop/android/components/menu/

However if you INSIST on having that design there are some options here:

https://android-arsenal.com/tag/142 (WheelView or WheelPicker)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pre-maid one, like [this](https://github.com/duanhong169/PickerView?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=7056)